# Why does an exception in LocalXAResourceImpl.commit() merely give a warning?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, wildfly, jca

In WildFly 8, I am using a distributed transaction containing an Oracle XA datasource and a custom JCA LocalTransaction resource (a connection to a file).

Basically it works as expected - if one of the resources fails to commit, the whole transaction is rolled back and neither the database nor the file is updated/written.

There is a special case however. Using JPA, if I am doing an `entityManager.merge(entity);` and the values of the entity are the same as those in the database, and writing to the file fails (i.e. because it does not exist), all I get is a warning and no exception thrown in my EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class JCABean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "file-tx") 
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource(name = "java:/FileDataSource")
    private IDataSource fileDataSource;

    public void insert(
            final long id, 
            final String value, 
            final boolean update) {

        final FileTxTest entity = new FileTxTest();
        entity.setId(id);
        entity.setValue(value);

        if (update) {
            entityManager.merge(entity);
        } else {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        }

        final File file = new File(FileHelper.BASE_PATH, 
                String.format("%s.txt", id));
        try (final IConnection connection = fileDataSource.getConnection(
                file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            connection.write(String.format("%s%n", value));
        }
    }
}
```

`fileDataSource.getConnection()` returns an instance of `FileConnection` implementing `LocalTransaction`.

If `file` is not writeable, `connection.commit()` throws a `ResourceException`.

If the value given to `entity.setValue()` equals the value in the database (and `update == true` so a merge is done), only this warning is issued:

```
16:33:58,276 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-4) ARJUNA016039: onePhaseCommit on < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff7f000101:842ac6d:56699b01:22, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff7f000101:842ac6d:56699b01:2a, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/FileDataSource > (LocalXAResourceImpl@1e22d60[connectionListener=e1ca39 connectionManager=1b9de9e warned=false currentXid=null productName=Generic JCA productVersion=1.0 jndiName=java:/FileDataSource]) failed with exception XAException.XA_RBROLLBACK: org.jboss.jca.core.spi.transaction.local.LocalXAException: IJ001156: Could not commit local transaction
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.LocalXAResourceImpl.commit(LocalXAResourceImpl.java:180) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.1.9.Final.jar:1.1.9.Final]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAOnePhaseResource.commit(XAOnePhaseResource.java:113)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.abstractrecords.LastResourceRecord.topLevelPrepare(LastResourceRecord.java:152)
```

If the entity being merged has an updated value, the whole transaction fails as expected:

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
```

So effectively, the "all or nothing" requirement is satisfied, but I'd like to have the transaction fail with an exception in any case so I can raise an error.

The Oracle XA datasource:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.domain.tld:1521:NAME
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</xa-datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

and the resource adapter:

```
<resource-adapters>
    <resource-adapter id="file-tx-jca.rar">
        <archive>
            file-tx-jca.rar
        </archive>
        <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
        <config-property name="Server">
            localhost
        </config-property>
        <config-property name="Port">
            19000
        </config-property>
        <connection-definitions>
            <connection-definition class-name="my.package.GenericManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/FileDataSource" pool-name="FileConnectionFactory">
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <application/>
                </security>
            </connection-definition>
        </connection-definitions>
    </resource-adapter>
</resource-adapters>
```

NOTE: I am aware that I can enlist at most one LocalTransaction resource (last resource) in a transaction. Since I might need to handle more than one file in the same transaction, I have changed the `FileConnection` and the `<resource-adapter>` to an `XAResource`/`XATransaction`. Here, the transaction always fails if a commit fails (i.e. by throwing an `XAException(XAException.XA_HEURHAZ)`). But I still would like to understand why there is only a warning logged if commit of a local transaction fails.

Is there some property I can set to get an exception even in that case where I currently only get a warning?

Comment: Could you share your EJB code?

Comment: Yes of course... done!

Comment: Could you also share your datasource configurations? Thanks

Comment: Also done - thanks for your interest

Comment: U're welcome. I'm wondering what happens when you remove all JPA related code to keep only the file writing code and then reproduce a writing failure? Could you share also file-tx resource code?

Comment: In this case, a `RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.` is thrown as expected. So the 1PC optimization incorrectly swallows the exception. In the file-tx code in `commit()`, simply the `IOException` is rethrown as `ResourceException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/lrco-overview.html) from JBOSS 5 EAP which describes the LRCO algorithm used when you enlist a single one-phase-aware resource in a transaction which involves other two-phase-aware resources:

> Although the XA transaction protocol is designed to provide ACID
>   properties by using a two-phase commit protocol, model may not always
>   be appropriate. Sometimes it is necessary to allow a non-XA-aware
>   resource manager to participate in a transaction. This is often the
>   case with data stores that do not support distributed transactions.
>
> In this situation, you can use a technique known as Last Resource
>   Commit Optimization (LRCO). This is sometimes called the Last Resource
>   Gambit. The one-phase-aware resource is processed last in the prepare
>   phase of the transaction, at which time an attempt is made to commit
>   it. If the attempt is successful, the transaction log is written and
>   the remaining resources go through the phase-two commit. If the last
>   resource fails to commit, the transaction is rolled back. Although
>   this protocol allows most transactions to complete normally, some
>   errors can cause an inconsistent transaction outcome. For this reason,
>   use LRCO as a last resort. When a single  is used
>   in a transaction, the LRCO is automatically applied to it. In other
>   situations, you can designate a last resource by using a special
>   marker interface. Refer to the JBoss Transactions Programmer's Guide
>   for more details.

My assumption is the following:
When you don't modify the merged entity, nothing is written in the undo log during the prepare phase of the two-phase-aware resource transaction.

Then, when the commit of the one-phase resource transaction fails (file write) which occurs at the end of the prepare phase, nothing has to be undone for the two-phase resource transaction. 
Therefore you don't get the RollbackException anymore, which corresponded to a rollback of the two-phase resource transaction involved in global transaction.

Comment: Your answer is very useful, it pointed me in the right direction and encouraged me to debug WildFly. The outcome of the prepare phase is `TwoPhaseOutcome.PREPARE_READONLY` so 1PC optimization is applied. There the `TwoPhaseOutcome.ONE_PHASE_ERROR` caused by the `XAException.XA_RBROLLBACK` is effectively ignored which I think is a bug, so I have reported one: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBTM-2584